# Error when installing Python packages with pip:

Tags: python, pip

I've been getting this error for a few weeks now. Sometimes package installs go perfectly, but other times I get an error. For example I tried installing Pygame today (Apologies, the error is pretty long):

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y965ak00\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y965ak00\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-07wtjukl'
         cwd: C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y965ak00\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y965ak00\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y965ak00\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y965ak00\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y965ak00\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I read a few suggestions like `pip(3) install setuptools` Which said `Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (50.3.2)` I also tried `pip install --upgrade pip` Which said `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (20.2.4)`

Neither of those solved the problem. I'm running Windows 10 if that matters. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because pygame has not yet released an update for your python version. Pygame has "pre" versions.

```
pip install pygame --pre
```